# how to reach end of file using fgetcsv in php

Tags: php, file, while-loop, eof

How to go until it reached the eof instead of 1000?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {...}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The second attribute of [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) defined the max length of line, not the max count of lines. You can set it to 0 to read an unlimited line length.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right.

Only that 1000 in the `fgetcsv` function is not the length of the document but the max character length of each line.

So you can omit it if you want.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php